# P&T Checkbox field not outputting on site?

Tags: custom-fields, pixelandtonic, pt-checkboxes

I've been working on a dev site for the past month or so. Everything was working fine. Started to upgrade the live site just now. It's pretty much all gone smoothly, except for 2 fields that are not showing on the site.

They are two P&T Checkbox custom fields. (Same channel). They are visible in the CP, and every entry has some options selected.

Now on the front end where I am displaying these options, nothing is output. It's the exact same template and set up that I am using in the dev site, which is working fine.

Not sure where to start trying or testing? Any ideas?

Comment: Hey shorn - where to start: lots more information. :) What version of EE, and of P&T Checkboxes are you on?  And can you add your template code to your original post?  Thanks!

Comment: Doh! Just went into the CP to start getting the P&T versions and then realised that I had not 'enabled' the field pack! Knew it would be something silly!

Comment: The field pack extension doesn't need to be enabled; so it is likely not that.  You'll see it stays on disabled, and is there for legacy compatibility.  Not that I'd object to it being that simple... ;)

Comment: Could you please write up your solution and accept it as the answer for this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, not sure based on the comments whether or not this was the actual reason it was solved, but when I enabled the "field pack" it then started showing. I already had the P&T checkboxes field enabled, and with just that, nothing was showing on the front end. Enabled the field pack, and all good.